# Search for commented out code using regex

Tags: c++, c, regex

Is there a quick way how to find commented out source code in C and C++ using regular expressions and grep ? I don want to find comments explaining the code but comments containing the source code

Comment: 1. What have you tried doing? 2. What do you need this for?

Comment: This page is a good resource for it: http://blog.ostermiller.org/find-comment

Comment: You might be able to this is a non trivial problem.  especially when you get into `/* ... */` comments.

Comment: The requirements you've set out are a bit loose; if there's a predefined style for commenting out code in your codebase then that makes it easier but just locating any old commented out code could prove challenging.  You could use a regex to locate any comments, and then run those comments through a parser to separate genuine comments and commented out source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not reliably, because doing so would require recognition of semantic meaning imbued by the programmer, which regular expressions cannot do. For example:

```
  /* This function looks for commented out code like this:
          // int x = 1;
  */
```

There is no way of a regex determining if `int x = 1;` is intended to be commented out code, or simply part of a comment that happens to be code.

Comment: I agree with "Not reliably" and beyond: It would even be next to impossible if you would use a compiler to detect compilability of commented lines. Using sed/perl/awk to activate commented code and then compile the file is theorectically possible. But it would be necessary to uncomment line by line and then try combinations of activating several commented lines, because one might only be compileable after another one has been compiled. And then you might find contradicting lines, i.e. one is only compilable when the other is inactive. And the other might be an active code line. Duration hell!